# Want final value of status against each ID in a logs.csv file - Pandas/Python

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a pandas data frame as follows

| Name | Marks latest |
| --- | --- |
| John | 32 |
| Sara | 43 |
| John | 45 |
| John | 82 |
| Sara | 69 |

What I want is a new data frame which only shows the final marks for each name:

| Name | Marks latest |
| --- | --- |
| John | 82 |
| Sara | 69 |

What's the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = df.drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')
print(out)

# Output
   Name  Marks latest
3  John            82
4  Sara            69
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby()`

```
df.groupby('Name', as_index = False)['Marks latest'].agg('last')
```